# How to retrieve dropdownlist selected value by providing manual id to Jquery function

Tags: jquery

Here is my Jquery function...I am Passing the ID of the dropdownlist to the jquery function..but it didn't work..please sugggest.

```
> function Calculatecost(count) {
>     
>     var id = "ddlProduct" + count;
>     var cost = $(id+"option:selected").val();
>     var quantity = $("#TextQuantity").val();
>     var totalcost = cost * quantity;
>     $("#TotalCost").text(totalcost); }
```

Comment: you forgot the #

Comment: You are missing a `#` at $(id and a space between the id and option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `#` and a space

```
function Calculatecost(count) {
   var id = "#ddlProduct" + count; // hash is missing
   var cost = $(id+" option:selected").val(); // space is missing
   var quantity = $("#TextQuantity").val();
   var totalcost = cost * quantity;
   $("#TotalCost").text(totalcost); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the # and need to select the child of the selected id therefore you need a space between the id and the option selector

```
 var id = "#ddlProduct" + count;
```

Don't forget to test if the numbers are valid, you don't want NaN in the totalcost